# I'm in trouble with .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying make to a social platform like Instagram or Facebook and I wanna to show users, username like that examplesite.com/usernamehere so in the url. I'd been researching how to do this and I learned it's made with htaccess rewrite codes. I have a code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Its working generally but for example when i want to enter to examplesite.com/login or register page, rewriterules thinks the word login or register is a username and it never opens. The folders must be open and also css, scss, js, img etc. folders on my server must be taken as a username, so if anyone examplesite.com/css, img or js etc. words write to url, should not be opened css, img or js files.

Sorry about my english. Thank everyone! <3

Answer (score 2):

A number of different things:

## Don’t use `.htaccess` files

There are numerous well-intended examples of code in `.htaccess` files that then get copied again and again by/for [*cargo cult* system administrators](https://lonesysadmin.net/2011/10/19/cargo-cult-system-administration/)  that should be reading the actual manual instead.

From: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

> In general, you should only use `.htaccess` files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a common misconception that user authentication should always be done in .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, **another misconception that mod_rewrite directives *must* go in  `.htaccess` files.** This is simply not the case.
> ...
> In the case of RewriteRule directives, in `.htaccess` context **these regular expressions must be re-compiled with every request to the directory, whereas in main server configuration context they are compiled once  and cached.** Additionally, the rules themselves are more complicated, as one must work around the restrictions that come with per-directory context and mod_rewrite. Consult the [Rewrite Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#htaccess)  for more detail on this subject.

## Second:

You mentioned a couple of directory names already that should be excluded from the `example.com/[user-alias]` mapping.

Don’t forget to also prohibit people from intentionally selecting those directory (and other) names as their user-alias as well in your sign up page.

## Last

`RewriteCond` directives are used to restrict the types of requests that will be subject to the following `RewriteRule`.

Your config currently says, in "plain" English, don’t apply the following `RewriteRule` when there is an existing file or directory with the same name as the file name component from the request.

You simply can add extra conditionals to that with extra `RewriteCond` lines, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !"login"
```

should exclude `example.com/login`